CRM Analytics App failing to create all components in a template
I have an app in crm analytics. It contains 4 datasets and 4 dashboards. I'm logged in as admin.
When I attempt to created a template from an app, only 2 of my datasets come over and no dashboards are created. When the app is being cheated it shows 3 user xmd files failing.
How can I troubleshoot?
